# Riverpod StreamProvider does not fire signout event for firebase auth

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, riverpod

I have a simple flutter application using [Riverpod](https://docs-v2.riverpod.dev/docs/why_riverpod). Also added a simple firebase project with "Anonymous sign in" functionality.

Using a `authProvider` as [StreamProvider](https://docs-v2.riverpod.dev/docs/providers/stream_provider) for application.

```
final firebaseAuthProvider = Provider<FirebaseAuth>((ref) => FirebaseAuth.instance);
final authProvider = StreamProvider<User?>((ref) => ref.watch(firebaseAuthProvider).authStateChanges());
```

A auth landing wrapper that checks if user is authenticated and shows either HomePage widget or LoginPage widget.

```
class AuthLanding extends ConsumerWidget {
  const AuthLanding({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return ref.watch(authProvider).when(
          data: (User? user) => user != null ? const HomePage() : const LoginPage(),
          error: (error, stackTrace) => const LoginPage(),
          loading: () => const Scaffold(body: Center(child: LinearProgressIndicator())),
        );
  }
}
```

I have a simple scaffold wrapper with drawer for two widgets HomePage and DemoPage.

```
class MyDrawerNav extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyDrawerNav({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: [
          const DrawerHeader(decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue), child: Text('Riverpod Demo')),
          ListTile(
            title: const Text("Home Page"),
            onTap: () {
              // exit drawer
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              // go to HomePage
              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const HomePage()));
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: const Text("Demo Page"),
            onTap: () {
              // exit drawer
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              // go to DemoPage
              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const DemoPage()));
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyScaffold extends ConsumerWidget {
  final Widget body;
  final String title;

  const MyScaffold({super.key, required this.body, required this.title});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    // Scaffold wrapper
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(title),
        forceMaterialTransparency: true,
      ),
      drawer: const MyDrawerNav(),
      body: body,
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends ConsumerWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return MyScaffold(
      title: "Home Page",
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: ref.watch(firebaseAuthProvider).signOut,
              child: const Text("Logout"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DemoPage extends ConsumerWidget {
  const DemoPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return MyScaffold(
      title: "Demo Page",
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const Text("Demo Page"),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: ref.watch(firebaseAuthProvider).signOut,
              child: const Text("Logout"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now it works as expected if users signs in, `AuthLanding` switches to `HomePage` widget and if user presses "Logout" button on HomePage it switches to LoginPage.

But the issue arises if user navigates to some other page (i.e. DemoPage) using drawer. Now if Logout button is pressed, `AuthLanding` does not change view to LoginPage. For some reason user has to go back to the first stacked route pressing back to see to LoginPage widget.

I don't understand why this does not work on other pages. Even if user uses drawer to go to DemoPage and then again use drawer to go to HomePage, it still does not change views.

Debugging showed that the AuthLanding widget does get re-rendered on a new event in `authProvider` but for some reason, current view remains the same.

Basically user has to pop all stacked routes and go back to first route to see LoginPage.

Could someone please explain if I'm doing something wrong in my code!?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

I tried to make my own Stream object and pass in a custom AuthUser based on firebase events. but still the same.

```
final userAuthProvider = StreamProvider.autoDispose<AuthUser>((ref) {
  AuthUser authUser = AuthUser();
  StreamController<AuthUser> controller = StreamController<AuthUser>();

  FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User? event) {
    if (event == null) {
      authUser = AuthUser(key: const ValueKey("Unauthorised"));
    } else {
      authUser = AuthUser(key: const ValueKey("Authorised"), user: event);
    }
    controller.add(authUser);
  });

  return controller.stream;
});

class AuthUser {
  final User? user;
  final Key? key;

  AuthUser({this.key, this.user}) {
    isAuthorised = user != null;
  }

  bool isAuthorised = false;
}
```

I think this may be an issue with the way i'm navigating to another page ?!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ref.watch(firebaseAuthProvider).userChanges()` instead of `ref.watch(firebaseAuthProvider).authStateChanges()`.

From the `userChanges` docs:

> Notifies about changes to any user updates. This is a superset of both
> [authStateChanges] and [idTokenChanges]. It provides events on all
> user changes, such as when credentials are linked, unlinked and when
> updates to the user profile are made. The purpose of this Stream is
> for listening to realtime updates to the user state (signed-in,
> signed-out, different user & token refresh) without manually having to
> call [reload] and then rehydrating changes to your application.

Comment: tried userChanges stream. It didn't work. I think the issue is not with firebase event not being fired. I checked this by using custom AuthUser object. Firebase event is being sent as expected.

Comment: @Usman OK, seems like I misunderstood your problem.